# trying to adjust a state object in redux but i can't change the value of one property in the object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

Ok so i have this very basic example of redux state

```
const initialState = {
  good: 0,
  ok: 0,
  bad: 0,
};

const counterReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  console.log(action);
  console.log(state);
  console.log(initialState);
  console.log(state.good);

  switch (action.type) {
    case "GOOD":
      return { ...state, good: good + 1 };
    case "OK":
      return { ...state, ok: ok + 1 };
    case "BAD":
      return { ...state, bad: bad + 1 };

    case "ZERO":
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default counterReducer;
```

i'm trying to change only one property of the state object on an onclick function named like this

```
const store = createStore(reducer);

const App = () => {
  const addGood = () => {
    store.dispatch({
      type: "GOOD",
    });
  };
  const addBad = () => {
    store.dispatch({ type: "BAD" });
  };
  const addOk = () => {
    store.dispatch({ type: "OK" });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={addGood}>good</button>
      <button onClick={addOk}>ok</button>
      <button onClick={addBad}>bad</button>
      <button>reset stats</button>
      <div>good {store.getState().good}</div>
      <div>ok {store.getState().ok}</div>
      <div>bad{store.getState().bad}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

const renderApp = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
};

renderApp();
store.subscribe(renderApp);
```

but when i try to change the value of any of the properties it doesn't work , for example good , ok , bad but it crashes my app if i do so with good is not defined error

Comment: `good`, `bad` and `ok` are not variables, so trying to access `good` standalone won't work. So doing `{ ...state, good: good + 1 }` will throw an error as `good` isn't defined. They are properties of your state object, which you can access using `state.good`, `state.bad` and `state.ok`

Answer (score 2):

You have to replace `good: good + 1` with `good: state.good + 1`, Likewise for other state, make these changes. `state.{property}` returns the current value of  that property in the state before being updated.